# Erasing vector::end from vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, language-lawyer, erase

Does it works correct(does nothing) when I use

```
 vector<T> v;
 v.erase(v.end());
```

I want to use something like

```
 v.erase(std::find(...));
```

Should I `if` is it `v.end()` or not?
There is no info about it on [C++.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) and [CPPreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The standard doesn't quite spell it out, but `v.erase(q)` is defined, "Erases the element pointed to by `q`" in `[sequence.reqmts]`. This means that `q` must actually point to an element, which the end iterator doesn't. Passing in the end iterator is undefined behavior.

Unfortunately, you need to write:

```
auto it = std::find(...);
if (it != <the part of ... that specifies the end of the range searched>) {
    v.erase(it);
}
```

Of course, you could define:

```
template typename<Sequence, Iterator>
Iterator my_erase(Sequence &s, Iterator it) {
    if (it == s.end()) return it;
    return s.erase(it);
}

my_erase(v, std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), whatever));
```

`c.erase()` on an associative container returns `void`, so to generalize this template to all containers you need some `-> decltype` action.

Comment: [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) says that " erasing elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate...". It looks like alowing of end() as parameter. And nowhere said the opposite explicitly. I dont like this...

Comment: @Pavel: then you'll have to take it up with the authors of "cplusplus.com". It is *not* the C++ documentation, the standard is the C++ documentation. But it defines `position` as "Iterator pointing to a single element". An end iterator does not point to a single element.

Comment: @Pavel They've got it wrong. It should say `end() - 1` instead of "vector end".

Answer (score 30):

Erasing `end()` (or for that matter, even looking at the target of `end()`) is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is allowed to have any behavior, including "just work" on your platform. That doesn't mean that you should be doing it; it's still undefined behavior, and I'll come bite you in the worst ways when you're least expecting it later on.

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to consider `set` or `unordered_set` instead of `vector` here.

Comment: thanks, i do know what is UB, I just was wanted to know, is it really UB.

Comment: @RiaD: Yes, it is UB. The solution is very simple, though, just check before you erase: `{ auto it = v.find(x); if (it != x.end()) { v.erase(it); } }`

Comment: Question for you @Billy. Out of curiosity, does end()-1 work? How is this different from pop_back()?

Comment: @Gaffi: `end-1` will work if and only if the container is not empty. (Same as `pop_back`)

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes I know I can check, it's quite easy:D. It just some ugly and I was thinking about replacing it:)

Comment: @Billy, set and even multiset is not OK for me. deletion will very rare operation.

Comment: @RiaD: Ok; just wanted to throw it out there. (Most often when I see people asking for this they're treating vectors as sets)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), (<your criteria>)), v.end());
```

Comment: Lack of other correct answers does not make your answer correct.

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted (other than maybe an initial answer that has been edited). The code as it stands is correct.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: As originally posted, it was not correct. Now that it has been edited to be correct, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: i needn't `remove_if`, I guess

Comment: It'll delete ALL elements with <criteria>, not first only

Comment: What is your criteria? What it is you are trying to std::find()?

Comment: It's not clear to me why we believe this to be safe while `vec.erase(vec.end())` clearly isn't

Comment: Like why should `vec.erase(vec.end(), vec.end());` be ok when `vec.erase(vec.end())` isn't

Comment: @bobobobo Because `vec.erase(vec.end(), vec.end())` erases a range (that happens to be zero-sized and so refers to zero items). `vec.erase(vec.end())` attempts to erase an item that doesn't exist.