# Is passing vector's end() to std::vector::erase valid?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

A very simple question but I couldn't find an answer. It would make awful lot of sense for it to be allowed but want to double-check.

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 0);
v.erase(v.end()); // allowed or not?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erasing vector::end from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590117/erasing-vectorend-from-vector)

Comment: @KenY-N: yes, that is the same question, but the answers here are better - I find them clearer, more to the point and easier to understand. I would rather mark the other one as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An invalid position or range causes undefined behavior.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the **end()**
>   iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as
>   a value for pos.

Comment: Well that sucks. Thank you. I wonder why they decided to go this way: makes `v.erase(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), item))` invalid.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe perhaps you are searching for the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)? `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), item), v.end());`

Comment: @Fiktik: hmm, perhaps. But looks like overkill for removing just a single item.

Comment: @Fiktik No. The remove keeps searching the list for duplicates. If std::find works, then std::remove is an inefficient substitute. You only need to use std::remove when there are potential duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 1):

For the single argument overload it is NOT valid to pass `end()` to `std::vector::erase`, because the single argument overload will erase the element AT that position.  There is no element at the `end()` position, since `end()` is one past the last element.

However, `end()` can be passed to the overload of `erase` that takes an Iterator range:

```
vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end())
```

Comment: I was referring to a single argument `erase` overload.