# Why erase cause an error on my mac? (c++)

Tags: c++, macos

My code works okay on my linux. Today when I was trying to compile it and test it on my mac, I got an segv error. And later I changed it to another method (not using `erase`), the error is gone. I guess that I must have done something wrong in using c++ `erase`. Any ideas?

### Before: (Why this one is not working now?)

```
vector<point> line::internalPoints() const
{
    vector<point> pts = points();

    pts.erase(pts.begin());
    pts.erase(pts.end());

    return pts;
}
```

### After:

```
vector<point> line::internalPoints() const
{
    vector<point> pts;
    vector<point> ptsTmp = points();

    for (int i = 1; i < ptsTmp.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        pts.push_back(ptsTmp[i]);
    }

    return pts;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to ask. Is there an issue with your current code?

Comment: " I got an error" is meaningless, unless you tell us what the error was you got.

Comment: It's a segv error. My question is why the first method using erase is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

end() (and possibly begin() as well, if the vector is empty) don't point to an actual element. That means trying to erase it is undefined behaviour.

Possible duplicate of: [erasing vector::end from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590117/erasing-vectorend-from-vector)

Comment: Hmm, but the vector is not empty. Furthermore, why on my ubuntu, it works without any warning? Are you saying it depends on the compiler or depends on the archetcture?

Comment: Read the link: "Undefined behavior is allowed to have any behavior, including "just work" on your platform. That doesn't mean that you should be doing it; it's still undefined behavior, and I'll come bite you in the worst ways when you're least expecting it later on."

Comment: Okay, +1 for your link. I see now what a "undefined behavior" means. Thanks