# std::remove with vector::erase and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

All over the web I see people use the [erase/remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) for C++ vectors like so:

```
#include <vector> // the general-purpose vector container
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // remove and remove_if
int main()
{
  // initialises a vector that holds the numbers from 0-9.
  std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  // removes all elements with the value 5
  v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), 5 ), v.end() );

  return 0;
}
```

That is, if I want to erase all elements matching some criteria (e.g. the number 5 from a vector of `int`s), then I use `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` in conjunction with `vector.erase` like so:

```
vector.erase( std::remove( vector.begin(), vector.end(), <some_value>), vector.end());
```

This works nicely in general; `std::remove` (and `remove_if`) will copy (or use move semantics in C++11) the elements that are to be deleted over to the end of the vector, so the vector from our previous example will now look like this:

> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, **5** };

With the element **5** bolded because it's been moved to the end.

Now, `std::remove` will return an iterator to it, which we then use in `erase` to clear the elements out. Nice.

### But what about the following example?

```
int main()
{
  // initialises an empty vector.
  std::vector<int> v = {};

  // removes all elements with the value 5
  v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), 5 ), v.end() );

  return 0;
}
```

This seems to work as expected (not erasing anything, not segfaulting, etc.) on all platforms I run it on, but I know that just because something is working, doesn't mean it's not undefined behavior.

The quick [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) for `vector.erase` says this (emphasis mine):

```
iterator erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
```

`first, last` are

> Iterators specifying a range within the vector] to be removed: `[first,last)`. i.e., the range includes all the elements between `first` and `last`, **including the element pointed by first** but not the one pointed by `last`.
>    Member types `iterator` and `const_iterator` are random access iterator types that point to elements.

### So is `vector.erase(vector.end(),vector.end())` undefined behavior?

Here's what the quick reference says about exception safety:

> If the removed elements include the last element in the container, no exceptions are thrown (no-throw guarantee).
>    Otherwise, the container is guaranteed to end in a valid state (basic guarantee).
>    An invalid `position` or `range` causes undefined behavior.

So, the answer, at least to me appears to be "YES", and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9590202/27678) seems to support it.

### Therefore, is the common idiom wrong?

Assuming it's undefined behavior, then any call to `remove` could return an iterator to `vector.end()` which should be checked before calling `vector.erase`, and calling remove on an empty vector does seem to return `vector.end`: ([IDEOne for code below](http://ideone.com/7sodQA))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<int> myInts;
   auto anIter = std::remove(myInts.begin(),myInts.end(),5);
   if (anIter == myInts.end())
      std::cout << "iterator = myInts.end()";
}
```

### Finally, my question:

Should the actual remove/erase idiom be this?

```
auto endOfRangeIterator = std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), <value>);
if (endOfRangeIterator != vector.end())
   vector.erase(endOfRangeIterator, vector.end())
```

Comment: No, an empty range is fine. `[first, first)` is an empty set.

Comment: *std::remove (and remove_if) will copy (or use move semantics in C++11) the elements that are to be deleted over to the end of the vector* Actually, they move elements that are **not** to be deleted to the **front** of the vector. The contents of the vector past the iterator returned are indeterminate.

Comment: @BoBTFish I agree that it should be fine, but according to the standard is it? The quick ref mentions that `vector.erase` will always erase the first element given. A naïve implementation of it could perhaps cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndyG: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase (generally better than cplusplus.com) has the same definition as the standard (removes stuff from the range [f,l) )

Comment: In your "Finally, my question" section, you are using the single argument version of erase. For that case, you must be sure that the iterator is dereferenceable.  But the remove/erase idiom uses the range erase version, which requires 2 iterators, neither of which need to be dereferenceable if they denote an empty range.

Comment: the quotation is correct and contains the answer: "including the element pointed by first but not the one pointed by last"

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: Actually, the quotation is not correct. In the case where `first==last`, the quote contradicts itself, specifying that an element is removed, but not removed. Which explains why AndyG came to believe it was undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley why? first points to end which is not an element of vector thus is not included. This is same as what C++ Standard says in24.2.1/7: 'range [i,j) refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by i and up to but not including the element pointed to by j"

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: It's not the same. The standard doesn't actually say that the element pointed to by `i` is included in the range. It just says that's where the range starts. It does, however, definitely say that the element pointed to by `j` is *not* included. Also, the second iterator passed to `erase` does not necessarily have to be the end iterator, so if `first==last`, that does not necessarily imply that first points to end.

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: To be clear, read the quote from cplusplus.com, replacing "last" with "first".  *"including the element pointed to by first, but not the one pointed to by first"*. The statement is clearly a contradiction, in that case.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley cplusplus says that (end,end) is a range that includes all the elements between end and end, including the element pointed by end but not the one pointed by end, which must be of type range [end,end) which is correct

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: A statement which contradicts itself cannot be correct. How can an element be included but not included?

Comment: this is element **pointed by**, since end doesn't point to element there is no elements in range

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2: You're assuming that the iterators are end iterators. That need not be the case. -- http://ideone.com/rcYPev -- In that code example, is the first element erased? If I go by the cplusplus.com documentation, it tells me "it is but it isn't", which is a contradiction.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes, in this case this is not correct, you are right

Comment: Eventually we will [erase_if](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33523825/1708801) which will simplify this whole thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> **24.2.1/7** Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges. A range is a pair
>   of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation.
>   **A range `[i,i)` is an empty range**; in general, a range `[i,j)` refers to the elements in the data structure starting with the element
>   pointed to by `i` and up to but not including the element pointed to
>   by `j`.

Emphasis mine.

Further, the description of `erase` you cite is not the normative text in the standard. The standard has this to say (Table 100):

> `a.erase(q1,q2)`
>
> *Effects*: Erases the elements in the range [q1, q2).

This doesn't require that `q1` be dereferenceable. If [q1, q2) is an empty range (per 24.2.1/7), then no elements are in the range, and so none are erased.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The definition of empty range according to the standard does wonders to clear things up; otherwise I think it would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

I think the more important in your cite is:

> Iterators specifying a range within the vector] to be removed:
>   [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first
>   and last, including the element pointed by first **but not the one
>   pointed by last**. Member types iterator and const_iterator are random
>   access iterator types that point to elements.

As we have found in comments, this citation from [cpluspluc.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) is incorrect. This will not violate the rules in case of `( v.end, v.end)` but will be incorrect in case of

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    v.erase( v.begin(), v.begin());
}
```

because statement that contradicts itself with

> the range includes (...), **including** the element pointed by
>   v.begin() **but not the one** pointed by v.begin().

cannot be a valid statement.

C++ Standard n3337 in **§** 23.2.2 Sequence containers requirements  Table 100 specifies that

`a.erase(q1,q2)` returns `iterator` . And note is:

> Requires: For vector and deque, T shall be MoveAssignable. Effects:
>   **Erases the elements in the range [q1, q2)**.

And this is what it says about the range `[i,j)` in **§** 24.2.1/7 Iterator requirements

> Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data
>   structures have interfaces that use ranges. A range is a pair of
>   iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation. A
>   range [i,i) is an empty range; in general, **a range [i,j) refers to the**
>   **elements in the data structure starting with the element pointed to by**
>   **i and up to** **but not including the element pointed to by j**. Range [i,j)
>   is valid if and only if j is reachable from i. The result of the
>   application of functions in the library to invalid ranges is
>   undefined.

Thus to answer your questions

> But what about the following example?

cplusplus.com is wrong in this case

> So is vector.erase(vector.end(),vector.end()) undefined behavior?

**No, no undefined behavior is triggered.**

> Therefore, is the common idiom wrong?

No, it is correct.

> Should the actual remove/erase idiom be this?

There is no need for this, though it is also fine.

Answer (score 4):

> So is vector.erase(vector.end(),vector.end()) undefined behavior?

No. Because of the statement right next to the one you emphesized:

> Iterators specifying a range within the vector] to be removed: [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first **but not the one pointed by last**.

So, `vector.erase(vector.end(),vector.end())` does not attempt to erase `vector.end()` because it is pointed to by parameter `last`.

Granted, this definition is ambiguous and those statements can be interpreted as contradictory. The quoted wording is not used by the standard.