# Why is a convenience helper for the erase-remove-idiom not provided by the standard?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, erase-remove-idiom

Removing items from a collection in the STL requires a technique used so often that is has become an idiom: [the erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

One of the most common usages of this idiom is to remove an item of type `T` from a `vector<T>`

```
std::vector<Widget> widget_collection;
Widget widget;

widget_collection.erase(
    std::remove(widget_collection.begin(), widget_collection.end(), widget), 
    widget_collection.end());
```

This is obviously very verbose, and violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - the vector in question is required 4 times there.

So my question is why does the standard not provide a convenience helper?

Something like

```
widget_collection.erase_remove(widget);
```

or

```
std::erase_remove(widget_collection, widget);
```

This could obviously be extended to

```
widget_collection.erase_remove_if(widget, pred);
```

etc...

Comment: You cold always write your own.

Comment: I have! :) I just thought it would be a fairly simple addition to `<algorithm>` so all could benefit from it

Comment: @SteveLorimer I have too. Do you specialize on `list<>`?

Comment: @curiousguy I don't, because I just use `list::erase`. It could certainly be made more generic. I'm glad `N4273` is accepted as it is definitely more elegant and has wider coverage than my implementation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is covered by proposal [N4009: Uniform Container Erasure](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4009.htm) which says:

> This is a proposal to add erase_if(container, pred), making it
>   easier to eliminate unwanted elements correctly and efficiently.
>
> [...]
>
> It's surprisingly difficult to eliminate unwanted elements from a container,
>   given a predicate that distinguishes "bad" elements from "good" elements.
>
> One of the STL's major strengths is that all of its containers have similar
>   interfaces - they have many functions in common and they follow the same
>   conventions.  When container interfaces vary, fundamental differences between
>   their data structures are responsible.  Even those differences can often be
>   ignored, thanks to the STL's container-iterator-algorithm design.

and also notes:

> The correct response
>   is to use the erase-remove idiom, which is non-obvious and must be taught
>   instead of discovered (it's called an "idiom" for a reason).

the latest version [N4273: Uniform Container Erasure (Revision 2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4273) looks like it was [adopted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/sd-1.htm). It is part of [Extensions for Library Fundamentals V2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4336.html) . Also see the cppreference section for [C++ standard libraries extensions, version 2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions_2).

The head revision(*version 6.0.0*) of gcc available on Wandbox has an implementation of this header (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1fo2VHdnr1MzD5t1)*):

```
#include <experimental/vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6} ;

    std::experimental::erase_if( v1, [] (const int &x ) { return x < 4; } ) ;

    for( const auto & v : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << v << ", " ;
    }
    std::cout << "\n" ;
}
```

This code also work on [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) which seems to confirm T.C.'s suggestion that this also shipped with MSVC 2015.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can find information on the release schedules for these extensions? Are they part of C++14?

Comment: @SteveLorimer no, I have not been paying as much attention to the libraries work as the core working group. But here [STL says likely C++17](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9050267) for his proposal.